# Will forwarding my abc.com url to www.abc.com break the mx records for '@' root?

Tags: domain, web-hosting, forwarding

I have a website, which uses cname for its www.abc.com hosting.
I am also using zoho mail service, so the root '@' mx record points to the zoho servers.

I want to use the cname for the "abc.com" domain. To do that, can I forward the URLs from abc.com to www.abc.com.

Would it break the mx records ?

Comment: How are you forwarding? As long as you're not using a CNAME (forbidden by RFCs) it should be fine.

Comment: I am using the simple Domain forwarding feature provided by most of the domain hosting services. For example, godaddy.

Comment: Then it'll be fine as long as your MX records remain intact.

Answer (score 2):

As ceejayoz stated in the comment, you can't actually have a CNAME for example.com like you can for www.example.com (which is actually a subdomain). So the A-record for example.com would have to point to a server that handles the redirect to example2.com.

As this is not related to the MX-record, it will have no impact on it.
As a note for others, this would not be the case if your MX-record looks like:
MX : example.com